# Chrome: restrict access to DevTools

Tags: jwt

I've created a SPA that is launched as a chrome app (a kind of kiosk browser).
This setting remove every navigation tool (nav bar, ulr bar, tab selection, options, etc.) from the browser.
I'm also disabling F12 and the mouse right click action (in JS) because I don't want that the user have access at the DevToll.
I'm doing all these also (and mainly) because at the moment my JWT is stored in the Session Storage.
My questions are: 
1) Is there any other way to access at DevTool that I'm not aware of? 
2) Is there any chance that someone can access at the Session Storage and read the content with all these precautions?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot stop users from accessing DevTools. It's very easy to enable mouse right click with chrome extension. And do not save your important things in session storage

Comment: @ZeroCho: thanks for your comment, but in kiosk mode, based on what I know, there is no manual access at chrome's extensions, the user cannot activate them manually. About your second point: you're right and I'm trying to find a way to store it somewhere else, but still I need to avoid access to DevTools anyway.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a JWT that it doesn't matter if they get hold if it, since you can verify its authenticity by the signature? If you are including something in a JWT you dont want people to be able to ever see, a jwt may not be the right tool for the job